# BitcoinJ - How to Create a wallet properly. (seeds, etc...)

Tags: bitcoinj

I'm learning this as fast as possible for a project. However the documentation, I find is lacking and/or not super super clear.

That said, Using BitcoinJ, I would like to know how to do the following:

**1. Create a wallet**

2. Send bitcoins to an address
3. Receive Bitcoins from an address
4. Synchronize the transaction with the wallet I have on disk.

For now, simply understanding how to CREATE the wallet. This involves the seed, etc... Ideally this can be via the WalletAppKit. But I'd like to learn either way of doing this as well. I know I can simply do: Wallet wallet = new Wallet(); BUT this feels inadequate. I should be providing it a seed or something more, which I'd be keeping private.

I added steps 2,3,4 above as these will be the other questions I need information on as I progress. For example, We'll say I already have a wallet. My app is offline, I then use an exchange and buy 1 bitcoin. When I start my app. How do I "synchronize" my wallet I have on disk, with the transaction that was performed. Thus Steps 3 and 4 might work hand in hand, since i'm receiving the bitcoins via "synchronizing", it means i'm receiving the bitcoins into my wallet which will then be saved to disk.

Once I know the answer on how to properly create the Wallet. I'll be curious what's the right way to send bitcoins to another address. Ie: WalletAppKit.wallet().SendTo, Should I be creating a transaction, or etc etc... But these can all be answered once I figure out the proper way for step 1.

Let me know if this is a bit more concise, and more detailed a question :-)

Thanks :D

Comment: *"Please explain how to create a wallet app with `bitcoinj`"* seems awfully broad for a single question post. Please isolate smaller topics and ask about them separately.

Comment: Hey Murch :) I reworded it so it's primarily focused on question 1. However I will eventually be asking 2,3 and 4. But those are not mandatory to be answered unless someone ovbiously has time to answer it.

This would be specific to BitcoinJ/Java. I've seen a few ways to create a wallet, but i'm curious what people here feel is the correct proper way of creating the wallet.

Comment: I don't think it got much clearer, but if you want other users to vote on it, please use the "reopen" link to add your question to the reopen vote queue. – That said, I think the question could be improved by explaining what you would like to know, if `Wallet wallet = new Wallet()` doesn't do what you describe as "create a wallet".